# Convert GL modelview matrix to world coordinates

Tags: c++, opengl-es, matrix, qcar-sdk

I'm using Qualcomm's AR SDK to track an object.
I have the following functions available:

https://ar.qualcomm.at/qdevnet/api (specifically look at "Namespace List->QCAR::Tool").

I can get the tracked item's modelview matrix by using the convertPose2GLMatrix (const Matrix34F &pose) function, as I get a pose matrix for each tracked item.

My goal - to determine the marker's location in "the real world". You can assume my camera will be stationary.

I have read numerous articles online, and my general understanding is this:
I need to pick a modelview matrix from where I choose the axis' 0,0,0 point to be (i.e. - copy the matrix I get for that point).
I then need to transpose that matrix. Then, each model view matrix I extract should be multiplied by that matrix and then by an (x,y,z,1) vector, to obtain the coordinates (ignoring the 4th item).

Am I correct? Is this the way to go? And if not - what is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to think of ortho matrices as moving from one coordinate space to another, so what  you suggest is correct, yet I would do it the other way around:

1.) Use a reference coordinate system S relative to your camera (i.e. just one of your matrices determined by the pose estimation)
  2.) For each pose estimation T calculate the following:

W = S * T^-1 = S * transpose(T)

3.) From matrix W pick the 4 column, as your world position.

Comment: Hi Christoper, unfortunately I couldn't fit my follow up question in a comment, so I wrote my follow up question in an "answer" below

Comment: Ok, it seems my multiplication function has an error. I'll fix it and report the results :-)

Comment: Thank you, I fixed the matrix multiplication method, and I think it works ok now. the last row (not column) gives me the world coordinates. Marked answer as accepted.